# JVM fork options for Gradle task test from Java plugin

Tags: java, gradle, jvm

I have two Gradle tasks with type test (from Java Gradle plugin):

```
task testsA(type: Test) {
  useTestNG {
    includeGroups 'typeA'
  }
  systemProperty 'hostname' 'localhost'
}

task testsB(type: Test) {
  useTestNG {
    includeGroups 'typeB'
  }
  systemProperty 'hostname' 'localhost'
}
```

This `systemProperty()` method comes from Java plugin and it calls `systemProperty()` on `DefaultJavaForkOption` object, which is private and final.

Is there a way to set fork system property "hostname" once (in other method or as a variable) and then use it in both of those tasks?

Note that I'm not interested in defining gradle variable "hostname" and then reusing it as a value for systemProperty method.

Comment: One idea that comes to my mind is to define a task with common logic. Also, is to possible to just call `systemProperty` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: problem is you cannot use DefaultJavaForkOption outside of the task which launches tests on forked JVM. It is not possible to call systemProperty on root project- this method is specific to Java plugin task Test.

Comment: What about `tasks.withType(Test) { systemProperty "hostname" "localhost" }` ?

Comment: Yes it works :) Answer officialy so that I can accept that as an answer

Comment: Will later on. On my way home right now 

Comment: Added the answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope:

```
tasks.withType(Test) { 
   systemProperty "hostname" "localhost" 
}
```

does the job, however I can't test it.